# Regular expression for replicate weights in complex survey R package

Tags: r, survey

I was using the survey package in R for analyzing data from the National Crime Victimization Survey. Thomas Lumley's book *Complex Surveys: A guide to analysis using R* and the help files in his survey package use a regular expression for the replicate weights that looks like this, `PERREPWGT[1-160]+`. However, this expression does not always identify all of the replicate weight. If I change the + sign to a ? sign, the regular expression works fine and identifies all of the replicate weights. A short test case is shown below. I am not very confident with regular expressions. Is this the correct change to the regular expression or is there a more reliable way to write the pattern?

```
x<-c("V3067", "V3068", "V3069", "V3070", "V3071", "V3072", "V3073", "V3074", "V3075", "V3076", "V3077", "V3078", 
"V3079", "V3080", "WGTPERCY", "V3081", "V3082", "PERREPWGT1", "PERREPWGT2", "PERREPWGT3", "PERREPWGT4", 
"PERREPWGT5", "PERREPWGT6", "PERREPWGT7", "PERREPWGT8", "PERREPWGT9", "PERREPWGT10", "PERREPWGT11", 
"PERREPWGT12", "PERREPWGT13", "PERREPWGT14", "PERREPWGT15", "PERREPWGT16", "PERREPWGT17", "PERREPWGT18", 
"PERREPWGT19", "PERREPWGT20", "PERREPWGT21", "PERREPWGT22", "PERREPWGT23", "PERREPWGT24", "PERREPWGT25", 
"PERREPWGT26", "PERREPWGT27", "PERREPWGT28", "PERREPWGT29", "PERREPWGT30", "PERREPWGT31", "PERREPWGT32", 
"PERREPWGT33", "PERREPWGT34", "PERREPWGT35", "PERREPWGT36", "PERREPWGT37", "PERREPWGT38", "PERREPWGT39", 
"PERREPWGT40", "PERREPWGT41", "PERREPWGT42", "PERREPWGT43", "PERREPWGT44", "PERREPWGT45", "PERREPWGT46", 
"PERREPWGT47", "PERREPWGT48", "PERREPWGT49", "PERREPWGT50", "PERREPWGT51", "PERREPWGT52", "PERREPWGT53", 
"PERREPWGT54", "PERREPWGT55", "PERREPWGT56", "PERREPWGT57", "PERREPWGT58", "PERREPWGT59", "PERREPWGT60", 
"PERREPWGT61", "PERREPWGT62", "PERREPWGT63", "PERREPWGT64", "PERREPWGT65", "PERREPWGT66", "PERREPWGT67", 
"PERREPWGT68", "PERREPWGT69", "PERREPWGT70", "PERREPWGT71", "PERREPWGT72", "PERREPWGT73", "PERREPWGT74", 
"PERREPWGT75", "PERREPWGT76", "PERREPWGT77", "PERREPWGT78", "PERREPWGT79", "PERREPWGT80", "PERREPWGT81", 
"PERREPWGT82", "PERREPWGT83", "PERREPWGT84", "PERREPWGT85", "PERREPWGT86", "PERREPWGT87", "PERREPWGT88", 
"PERREPWGT89", "PERREPWGT90", "PERREPWGT91", "PERREPWGT92", "PERREPWGT93", "PERREPWGT94", "PERREPWGT95", 
"PERREPWGT96", "PERREPWGT97", "PERREPWGT98", "PERREPWGT99", "PERREPWGT100", "PERREPWGT101", "PERREPWGT102", 
"PERREPWGT103", "PERREPWGT104", "PERREPWGT105", "PERREPWGT106", "PERREPWGT107", "PERREPWGT108", "PERREPWGT109", 
"PERREPWGT110", "PERREPWGT111", "PERREPWGT112", "PERREPWGT113", "PERREPWGT114", "PERREPWGT115", "PERREPWGT116", 
"PERREPWGT117", "PERREPWGT118", "PERREPWGT119", "PERREPWGT120", "PERREPWGT121", "PERREPWGT122", "PERREPWGT123", 
"PERREPWGT124", "PERREPWGT125", "PERREPWGT126", "PERREPWGT127", "PERREPWGT128", "PERREPWGT129", "PERREPWGT130", 
"PERREPWGT131", "PERREPWGT132", "PERREPWGT133", "PERREPWGT134", "PERREPWGT135", "PERREPWGT136", "PERREPWGT137", 
"PERREPWGT138", "PERREPWGT139", "PERREPWGT140", "PERREPWGT141", "PERREPWGT142", "PERREPWGT143", "PERREPWGT144", 
"PERREPWGT145", "PERREPWGT146", "PERREPWGT147", "PERREPWGT148", "PERREPWGT149", "PERREPWGT150", "PERREPWGT151", 
"PERREPWGT152", "PERREPWGT153", "PERREPWGT154", "PERREPWGT155", "PERREPWGT156", "PERREPWGT157", "PERREPWGT158", 
"PERREPWGT159", "PERREPWGT160")


#Regular expression consistent with examples in survey package
#Does NOT identify all replicate weight names
grep("PERREPWGT[1-160]+", x)

#Correctly identifies array index 18 through 177
grep("PERREPWGT[1-160]?", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The example the original question is referencing uses a regexp like "WT[1-9]+" to specify any variable name with WT followed by at least one digit 1-9.  The 1-9 is important: in that dataset the sampling weights were WT0 and the regular expression was chosen to not pick up WT0.

Answer (score 0):

`[1-160]` isn't really a useful regular expression pattern.  you want to match all single digits 0-9, and allow more than one.  to do this, use `grep( "PERREPWGT[0-9]+" , x )`